# I can't change the name of a method in selenium with testNG

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

I have recently started working selenium and testng. I have a suite of tests that were written when I got here.

```
public class Teams {
    @BeforeClass
      public void setUp(){
    }

    @Test
    public void ProfilePage() throws InterruptedException {
    // elegance, 
    }

    @Test
    public void TeamFeed() throws InterruptedException{
    // truly
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void logout(){
    // beautiful code  
    }
}
```

Changing the name of the method "ProfilePage()" breaks the script. The output is an empty browser window with "data:," in the address bar.

I don't understand why changing this method name is breaking everything. I may be having a really dumb moment.

Comment: Not knowing how your build is setup, or if you're using any build managers like ant or maven...I'd say attempt to rebuild project. Then try to run the tests again.

Comment: Changing name will change the method order execution. If your tests are dependent, you have to add a `dependsOnMethods`.

Comment: Using dependsOnMethods works... Thank you. I can now change the multiple occurrences of ProfilePage() to appropriate method titles.  It appears that without any order specified, testNG will run the tests in alphabetical order. I am but an intern, and our main QA guy is out on vacation. He never used any notations after the @Test tags. Should dependsOn and the other annotations be being used? I can probably restructure our test suite (which is quite small at the moment) to a more robust set up that follows testNG standards. (If team lead agrees it's worth it).